# Problems with two DTD exercises

Tags: sql, xml, dtd

I've started a SQL course and I'm in XML right now but can't get past these two exercises that keep giving me errors.

Exercise 1 XML: https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/courses-ID.xml

My code:

```
<!ELEMENT Course_Catalog (Department*)>

<!ELEMENT Department (Title, Course+, Professor+, Lecturer?)>
<!ELEMENT Course (Title, Description?)>
<!ELEMENT Description (Courseref)>
<!ELEMENT Professor (First_Name, Middle_Initial?, Last_Name)>
<!ELEMENT Lecturer (First_Name, Middle_Initial?, Last_Name)>

<!ATTLIST Department Code IDREFS #REQUIRED
                     Chair IDREFS #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Course Number ID #REQUIRED
                 Prerequisites IDREFS #IMPLIED
                 Instructors IDREFS #REQUIRED
                 Enrollment CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST Professor InstrID IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Lecturer InstrID IDREF #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Courseref Number IDREF #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT First_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Middle_Initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Last_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Courseref (#PCDATA)>
```

Exercise 2 XML: https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/countries.xml

My code:

```
<!ELEMENT countries (Country*)>

<!ELEMENT Country (City? | Language?)*>
<!ELEMENT City (Name, Population)>

<!ATTLIST Country Name ID #REQUIRED
                  Population CDATA #REQUIRED
                  Area CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Language Percentage CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT Language (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Population (#PCDATA)>
```

First one gives me this error:

> /tmp/tmpfFfDHT.dtd:19: parser error : ATTLIST: no name for Attribute
>   `<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>`

Second one gives me this error:

> /home/sandbox/countries.xml:4: element country: validity error : No
>   declaration for element country

EDIT: Edited some errors people have pointed out, but both exercises are still giving me errors.

Comment: What kind of course is it that doesn't offer students any help?

Comment: Well it's not that it doesn't offer help, it does, there's a whole forum for Q&A, but I've posted there and no one has even answered. :/

Comment: You've received gracious help on the exact errors you've posted.  Your response to this help indicates that you're looking for someone to do all of your exercise for you, not that you're interested in learning.   Sorry, but that's not how this site works, and it's not what's best for your education either.

Comment: Sorry, that's not it? I mean the exercise IS done, both are supposed to be done anyway, but it's giving me errors that I can't figure out by myself. That's all. Your assumption is wrong and honestly, a bit offensive too. There's no need to be mean. I have never been mean to anyone EVER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both examples, I'm assuming only DTD changes are allowed and not changes to the XML.

**Example DTD #1**

The following DTD changes were necessary for the XML to validate:

- The element declaration for `Department` only allows for one occurrence of one or more `Professor` elements followed by zero or one `Lecturer` element. I changed this to allow for one or more occurrences of this. (Wrapped `Professor+, Lecturer?` in parens and added the `+` occurrence indicator.)
- There are two element declarations for `Description`. In the XML, `Description` has mixed content. Mixed content means it contains both text and child elements. There is only one way to declare mixed content so I updated the first declaration and deleted the second declaration. (See diff below.)
- There were multiple attributes declared with the attribute type `IDREF`. If an attribute is declared as an IDREF and is used in the XML, that value also has to exist in an attribute that is declared as an ID. I changed some of the IDREF types to ID for attributes that appeared to be IDs. (See diff below.)

Here is the new DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT Course_Catalog (Department*)>

<!ELEMENT Department (Title, Course+, (Professor+, Lecturer?)+)>
<!ELEMENT Course (Title, Description?)>
<!ELEMENT Description (#PCDATA|Courseref)*>
<!ELEMENT Professor (First_Name, Middle_Initial?, Last_Name)>
<!ELEMENT Lecturer (First_Name, Middle_Initial?, Last_Name)>

<!ATTLIST Department Code ID #REQUIRED
                     Chair IDREFS #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Course Number ID #REQUIRED
                 Prerequisites IDREFS #IMPLIED
                 Instructors IDREFS #REQUIRED
                 Enrollment CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST Professor InstrID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Lecturer InstrID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Courseref Number IDREF #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT First_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Middle_Initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Last_Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Courseref (#PCDATA)>
```

Here is a diff between your DTD (left) and the modified DTD (right):

[image: exercise 1 diff report]

**Example DTD #2**

The following DTD changes were necessary for the XML to validate:

- The element names in the DTD all have the first letter capitalized. The XML has all lower-case names. Changed the element names in the DTD to lower-case.
- In the element declaration for `country`, the model `(city? | language?)*` means zero or one `city` elements or zero or one `language` elements zero or more times. I simplified this to `(city|language)*` which means `city` or `language` elements zero or more times. This change wasn't required.
- The `name` attribute for the `country` element was declared with the type `ID`. The actual XML didn't appear to have ID's though. For example `Antigua and Barbuda` is not a valid ID. I changed this attribute to the `CDATA` type.

Here is the new DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT countries (country*)>

<!ELEMENT country (city|language)*>
<!ELEMENT city (name, population)>

<!ATTLIST country name CDATA #REQUIRED
        population CDATA #REQUIRED
        area CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST language percentage CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT population (#PCDATA)>
```

Here is a diff between your DTD (left) and the modified DTD (right):

[image: exercise 2 diff report]

Comment: Thanks. But it's still giving me errors, both exercises. Can you guys see any other mistakes? :/

Comment: @Evan - I've updated my answer. Please take a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! I gotta go but will try this tonight! I hope I can finally solve it with your help ^^

Comment: both validated! thank you SO MUCH! I suck at this tho lol, made so many mistakes... but your explanations are easy to follow, will definitely try to keep them in mind from now on, thanks again!

Comment: @Evan - Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I can't immediately see the first error, but the second one is that "country" and "Country" are two different names.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't fix it tho, keeps giving me error. :/

Answer (score 0):

**Exercise 1:** Add a `>` at the end of this line in the DTD:

```
<!ATTLIST Courseref Number IDREF #REQUIRED
```

**Exercise 2:** XML element names are case sensitive (as Michael Kay already mentioned).  Make your XML and DTD agree on the case of `country`.

Comment: Thanks. Did so, but the problem persists. :S